# Find and update an element in C++11 vector of structs

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I have a vector of struct as follows

```
struct myStruct{
    size_t aID;
    int bID;
    double tobeUpdated;
};

std::vector<myStruct> myVec;
```

how can I find and update a member of `myVec` which satisfies `aID == someId && bID == otherID` in an efficient way in C++11?

Comment: is the vector sorted?

Comment: well you're probably stuck with linear search.

Comment: how many elements do you want to update? maximally one? or could there be more than one?

Comment: there is maximally one element to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumes only one to be updated.

```
// what to search for
size_t aID = 5;
int bID = 7;

find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [aID, bID](const myStruct& obj) { return obj.aID == aID && obj.bID == bID; });
```

Comment: @polerto No it returns an iterator to the object, which you can use to update it, or the end iterator if the object isn't found.

Comment: doesn't it return a "copy" of the element that I am searching for? So if I update the returned iterator, wouldn't it only update the copy but not the element in the vector itself?

Comment: @polerto No, you need to learn more about STL. An iterator is like a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it more efficient, it really depends on your usage of the `struct` and array.  If it is possible based on how you use it, then I would store them in an `std::map` instead.  This will allow for easy lookup based on ID's or possibly a combination of ID's.  However, if it doesn't actually slow your system down noticeably, then I would say to forgo the optimization and just iterate through each index with that test.